# Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting the error message of

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

at this line:

```
Set hello = Range("O" & row, "Q" & row, "W" & row)
```

However, the macro runs smoothly with `Set hello = Range("O" & row)`. So it means this macro is okay with one cell selection, but getting error with multiple cells selection. I cannot figure out which setting in my macro causes this error. Appreciate your help.

```
Sub ImportDatafromotherworksheet()
Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
Dim rngSourceRange As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range
Dim row As Integer
Dim hello As Range
Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
        Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select source row", Title:="Source Range", Default:="press Ctrl for multiple selection", Type:=8)
        row = rngSourceRange.row
        Set hello = Range("O" & row, "Q" & row, "W" & row)

        wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
        Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        hello.Copy rngDestination
        rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        wkbSourceBook.Close False
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to end up with should be (e.g.) `Range("O5,Q5,W5")`

```
Set hello = Range("O" & row & ",Q" & row & ",W" & row)
```

the whole thing is one string, not three.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.Union` also works.

```
Set hello = Application.Union(Range("O" & row), Range("Q" & row), Range("W" & row))
```

Don't know if it's better than any other solution though.